# Custom TableViewCell Layout in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am trying to implement a custom layout in a table view cell in iOS 7. Try as I might I cannot add UI elements to the table view cell using the storyboard interface. Even dragging and dropping a label onto the prototype cell does not seem to work.

Am I going crazy? Is this still possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is still possible. Please make sure you selected the TableCell on the left side of the storyboard. I did it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the scene selected by double-clicking on it or selecting it in the left-hand navigator. If the scene is selected it will have a blue border around it.